# Will an out of proc session survive a windows azure VIP swap?

Tags: session, azure, virtual-ip-address

If I'm hosting a site in windows azure with an out of proc session provider and perform a VIP swap, will the session persist through the VIP swap since the session is being provided out of process?

I will come back and answer the question after I perform a test but I'm pretty sure someone will have the answer here asap and azure deployments take a while.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see no reason why it shouldn't work.

It should be no different than hitting different instances that are part of the same deploy.

Answer (score 1):

If you use the Azure Cache for your session, it should not. The browser is using the same domain, so the same cookie would be sent, and a VIP swap does not affect the cache server.

If you are not using Azure Cache for session I recommend it, they even have a NuGet package.

Comment: We are using the azure cache and its been great so far.  I didn't know they had a nuget package for it yet, cool!

Comment: Yes, the newest release was on Dec 7 after sdk 1.6. You might have to dig through nuget to find it, but it's there.

Comment: Nice, yeah we're using 1.6.  We'll have to start using nuget as of the next version, thanks!